# TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments:

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, client

I'm writing code for a chat app in Python for a school project, it's split into a client.py file and a server.py file, and for some reason every time I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\client.py", line 90, in <module>
    Client()
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'gui_thread', and 'receive_thread'
```

The code for the file is as follows:

```
from operator import truediv
import socket
import threading 
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import simpledialog


class Client:

    def __init__(self, msg, gui_thread, receive_thread):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(('localhost', 1234))

        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()

        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname", parent=msg)

        self.gui_done = False 
        self.running = True

        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)

        gui_thread.start()
        receive_thread.start()

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")
        
        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat:", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Message:", bg="Lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text="Send", command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.end_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)

        self.win.mainloop()

    def write(self):
        message =f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
        self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')


    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)

    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'NICK':
                    self.server.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print("Error")
                self.sock.close()
                break

    

Client()
```

Comment: When you create a `Client`, you have to specify `msg, gui_thread, receive_thread` according to the `__init__()` method's signature.

Comment: But the `__init__` method never uses the parameters, it reassigns all those variables. They probably shouldn't be in the method parameter list in the first place.

Comment: _"for some reason"_ - for exactly the reason it tells you, you're not passing arguments corresponding to the parameters you defined.

Comment: You have created two instances of `Tk()`.  Also better to run the tkinter GUI in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

That's incorrect usage of `__init__` method.

```
class Client:

def __init__(self):
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.connect(('localhost', 1234))
    
    # As you redefine msg var here it can be thrown from the __init__ params
    msg = tkinter.Tk()
    msg.withdraw()

    # self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname", parent=msg) I presume this shouldn't be itinitalized in __init__, do it in method instead

    self.gui_done = False 
    self.running = True

    # Same here, you redefine the thread
    self.gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
    self.receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)

    self.gui_thread.start()
    self.receive_thread.start()
```

I suggest you to create a method for getting message and expected threads for gui and receive. And use this method when necessary with accessing parameters via self.

```
def start_app(self, message):
    # Do whatever you want with message here via self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client()
    client.start_app("Your message you'd like to send")
```